# Are there nice functions for which $\sum\limits_{n\geq 1} f(n) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}_+}f(t)dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, summation, recreational-mathematics

What can we say about the class of functions for which $$\sum\limits_{n\geq 1} f(n) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}_+}f(t)dt$$
Are there any good examples of such functions?

Edit: You may prefer different summation/integration bounds like $n \geq 0$ or $t \geq 1$, doesn't really matter.

Comment: Perhaps one of the most straightforward examples would be a piecewise constant function defined on each integer interval, then the equality can be obtained by observing area of each strip is simply $((n + 1)- n) f(n) = f(n) $.

Comment: One example, albeit a little contrived, is

$$f(x) := \begin{cases}
\sin(x)/x & x \ge 1 \\
1/2 & 0 \le x < 1 \end{cases}$$

This comes from the identities

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d} x = \frac \pi 2 \qquad
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{n} = \frac{\pi - 1}{2}$$

(The idea came to mind from [a video I watched a few weeks ago](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGsvq_eAJYo) which referenced these.)

Comment: @EeveeTrainer $$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {f(x)dx}  = \frac{1}{2} + \int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\sin x}}{x}dx}  = \frac{{\pi  + 1}}{2} - \int_0^1 {\frac{{\sin x}}{x}dx}  = 1.1247132 \ldots  \ne 1.0707963\ldots = \frac{{\pi  - 1}}{2} = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\sin n}}{n}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {f(n)} 
$$

Comment: For the left-hand side you are using point-evaluations of $f$ which may be problematic if the class of $f$ you consider is too big (e.g. if $f\in L^1$). Thus you may want your $f$ to be continuous. In addition: if $f$ does not satisfy your identity you can change it on an arbitrarily small set (not containing the integers) such that the identity holds.

Comment: @Gary - My bad, I think I meant to put $-1/2$ in.

Comment: Something of the form $\frac{\sin x}{g(x)}$ where $g(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ is what first came to my mind also... There ae probably many contrived examples of this form...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula), if $f$ is an entire even function whose modulus does not grow too fast on the right half-plane,
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0} f(n) = \frac{f(0)}{2}+\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx. \tag{1}$$
*Folklore*: Growth conditions are a bit tricky, though. You might be induced to think that, by this principle,
$$ \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi^{1/4}}{\Gamma(3/4)}+1\right)=\sum_{n\geq 0} e^{-\pi n^2} \stackrel{\color{red}?}{=} 1 $$
but the difference between the LHS and the RHS, albeit small, is not zero. It is $\approx 0.04322$.
On the other hand $(1)$ works like a charm for computing series like
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{\sin n}{n}\right)^k\quad\text{or}\quad \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1-\cos n}{n^2}\right)^k$$
or for series involving values of Bessel functions.

Comment: [+1] There are also connections with [Euler-MacLaurin formula](https://people.csail.mit.edu/kuat/courses/euler-maclaurin.pdf), a workhorse for series/integrals comparison.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x) = \lfloor{x\rfloor}$, an example would be

$$\int_{0}^{n}f(x)dx = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(k)\ =\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{2},$$

or equivalently,

$$\int_{0}^{n}\lfloor{x\rfloor}dx = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k\ =\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{2}.$$